# Primefaces basic autocomplete not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying  [autocomplete demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf) .I am not getting any error but the httprequest/response shows that it is communicating with the server but not to the bean. I am using latest version of primefaces 3.4.

Any help is appreciated.

Bean :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import com.zreflect.emyed.managedbean.BaseMB;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CircleSearchBean extends BaseMB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String selected;
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> complete(String query) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            results.add(query + i);
        }
        return results;
    }
    /**
     * @return the selected
     */
    public String getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    /**
     * @param selected
     *            the selected to set
     */
    public void setSelected(String selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title><h:outputText value="test" /></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
<p:autoComplete value="#{circleSearchBean.selected}" completeMethod="#{circleSearchBean.complete}"/> 
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here's debug information from Chrome developer tools.

Request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/PrimefacesTest/faces/index.xhtml
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:157
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=60Wd6aXSj6rDbPOgvMCoFJFF.undefined
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/PrimefacesTest/faces/index.xhtml
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Form data:

```
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:j_idt8
javax.faces.partial.execute:j_idt8
javax.faces.partial.render:j_idt8
j_idt8:j_idt8
j_idt8_query:hello
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:346
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 02 Sep 2012 21:11:42 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
```

Comment: Can you add the full source of your bean? It's useful to see whether you're using CDI or JSF managed beans, what scope, etc...

Comment: @HoundDog i have edited and added full source of bean and xhtml page.

Comment: try removing the `extends BaseMB` from your `CircleSearchBean` class and check again...

Comment: @Daniel even taking off it don't work.

Comment: you press a letter "a" for example and nothing happens? any logs in firebug console ? or server logs? try placing break point in complete method is it being called at all ?

Comment: Out of interest, can you post your web.xml as well? (and faces-config.xml if you're using it). If you view the HTML you should see the javascript attached (e.g. `<script id="form:acSimple_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('AutoComplete','widget_form_acSimple',{id:'form:acSimple'});});</script>`). It won't fix anything, but you might also want to remove the `results` field - it's being shadowed in the `complete()` method.

Comment: To reduce code noise, please remove `extends BaseMB` and retry (and update question accordingly). As to "not getting an error", did you also read the server logs? By default (projectstage=Production) the client won't get any feedback on exceptions during ajax requests.

Comment: @Daniel There is no errors reported in server logs or console logs. When i ran it in debug mode it runs until the filter class(which checks whether the session is valid) and disappears. As i mentioned in the answer after placing "id" attribute it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working now as shown in demo after adding the "id" attribute to autocomplete.

```
<p:autoComplete id="autocomplete" value="#{circleSearchBean.selected}" 
   completeMethod="#{circleSearchBean.complete}"/>
```

In a seperate project it is working without an "id" attribute. Looks like a bug.